# Trying to update data into database from bootstrap modal

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I can't for the life of me figure out how to get the data into the database. On the front page of my website I have a table that is connected already to the database so basically I have made a back admin page to enter info faster and when it is entered in back admin page it will update database which will then update the table on the front of webpage. When I try to add info in modal and submit page goes blank except for add button.When I refresh all info is back on table. [table with info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5lSbF.png) ,[table after sumbit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IMI3e.png)

*troubled coder

```
  <?php  
 include_once 'core/init.php';
 $query = "SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY id DESC";  
 $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);  
 ?>  
 <!DOCTYPE html>  
 <html>  
      <head>  
           <title>Update Products</title>  
           <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>  
           <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />  
           <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>  
      </head>  
      <body>  
           <br /><br />  
           <div class="container" style="width:700px;">  
                <h3 align="center">Update MySQL Data</h3>  
                <br />  
                <div class="table-responsive">  
                     <div align="right">  
                          <button type="button" name="add" id="add" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#add_data_Modal" class="btn btn-warning">Add</button>  
                     </div>  
                     <br />  
                     <div id="products_table">  
                          <table class="table table-bordered">  
                               <tr>  
                                    <th width="70%">Products Name</th>  
                                    <th width="15%">Edit</th>  
                                    <th width="15%">View</th>  
                               </tr>  
                               <?php  
                               while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
                               {  
                               ?>  
                               <tr>  
                                    <td><?php echo $row["title"]; ?></td>  
                                    <td><input type="button" name="edit" value="Edit" id="<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>" class="btn btn-info btn-xs edit_data" /></td>  
                                    <td><input type="button" name="view" value="view" id="<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>" class="btn btn-info btn-xs view_data" /></td>  
                               </tr>  
                               <?php  
                               }  
                               ?>  
                          </table>  
                     </div>  
                </div>  
           </div>  
      </body>  
 </html>  
 <div id="dataModal" class="modal fade">  
      <div class="modal-dialog">  
           <div class="modal-content">  
                <div class="modal-header">  
                     <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>  
                     <h4 class="modal-title">Product Details</h4>  
                </div>  
                <div class="modal-body" id="products_detail">  
                </div> 
                <div class="modal-footer">  
                     <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>  
                </div>  
           </div>  
      </div>  
 </div> 
</div>  
 <div id="add_data_Modal" class="modal fade">  
      <div class="modal-dialog">  
           <div class="modal-content">  
                <div class="modal-header">  
                     <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>  
                     <h4 class="modal-title">Update Product MySQL</h4>  
                </div>  
                <div class="modal-body">  
                     <form method="post" id="insert_form">  
                          <label>Product</label>  
                          <input type="text" name="title" id="title" class="form-control" />  
                          <br />  
                          <label>Price</label>  
                          <input type="text" name="price" id="price" class="form-control" /> 
                          <br />  
                          <label>List Price</label>  
                          <input type="text" name="list_price" id="list_price" class="form-control" /> 
                          <br /> 
                          <label>Description</label>  
                          <textarea name="description" id="description" class="form-control" /></textarea>  
                          <br />  
                          <label>Condition</label>  
                          <input type="text" name="condition" id="condition" class="form-control" />  
                          <br />  
                          <input type="hidden" name="products_id" id="products_id" />  
                          <input type="submit" name="insert" id="insert" value="Insert" class="btn btn-success" />  
                     </form>  
                </div>  
                <div class="modal-footer">  
                     <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>  
                </div>  
           </div>  
      </div>  
 </div>  
 <script>  
 $(document).ready(function(){  
      $('#add').click(function(){  
           $('#insert').val("Insert");  
           $('#insert_form')[0].reset();  
      });  
      $(document).on('click', '.edit_data', function(){  
           var products_id = $(this).attr("id");  
           $.ajax({  
                url:"fetch.php",  
                method:"POST",  
                data:{products_id:products_id},  
                dataType:"json",  
                success:function(data){  
                     $('#title').val(data.name);  
                     $('#price').val(data.address);  
                     $('#list_price').val(data.gender);  
                     $('#description').val(data.designation);  
                     $('#condition').val(data.age);  
                     $('#products_id').val(data.id);  
                     $('#insert').val("Update");  
                     $('#add_data_Modal').modal('show');  
                }  
           });  
      });  
      $('#insert_form').on("submit", function(event){  
           event.preventDefault();  
           if($('#title').val() == "")  
           {  
                alert("Title is required");  
           }  
           else if($('#price').val() == '')  
           {  
                alert("Price is required");  
           }  
           else if($('#description').val() == '')  
           {  
                alert("Description is required");  
           }  
           else if($('#condition').val() == '')  
           {  
                alert("Condition is required");  
           }  
           else  
           {  
                $.ajax({  
                     url:"insert.php",  
                     method:"POST",  
                     data:$('#insert_form').serialize(),  
                     beforeSend:function(){  
                          $('#insert').val("Inserting");  
                     },  
                     success:function(data){  
                          $('#insert_form')[0].reset();  
                          $('#add_data_Modal').modal('hide');  
                          $('#products_table').html(data);   
                     }  
                });  
           }  
      });  
      $(document).on('click', '.view_data', function(){  
           var products_id = $(this).attr("id");  
           if(products_id != '')  
           {  
                $.ajax({  
                     url:"select.php",  
                     method:"POST",  
                     data:{products_id:products_id},  
                     success:function(data){  
                          $('#products_detail').html(data);  
                          $('#dataModal').modal('show');  
                     }  
                });  
           }            
      });  
 });  
 </script>
```

INSERT.PHP CODE

```
 <?php  
 include_once 'core/init.php';
 if(!empty($_POST))  
 {  
      $output = '';  
      $message = '';  
      $title = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["title"]);  
      $price = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["price"]);  
      $list_price = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["list_price"]);  
      $description = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["description"]);  
      $condition = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["condition"]);  
      if($_POST["products_id"] != '')  
      {  
           $query = "  
           UPDATE products   
           SET title='$title',   
           price='$price',   
           list_price='$list_price',   
           description = '$description',   
           condition = '$condition'   
           WHERE id='".$_POST["products_id"]."'";  
           $message = 'Data Updated';  
      }  
      else  
      {  
           $query = "  
           INSERT INTO products(title, price, list_price, description, condition)  
           VALUES('$title', '$price', '$list_price', '$description', '$condition');  
           ";  
           $message = 'Data Inserted';  
      }  
      if(mysqli_query($conn, $query))  
      {  
           $output .= '<label class="text-success">' . $message . '</label>';  
           $select_query = "SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY id DESC";  
           $result = mysqli_query($conn, $select_query);  
           $output .= '  
                <table class="table table-bordered">  
                     <tr>  
                          <th width="70%">Product Name</th>  
                          <th width="15%">Edit</th>  
                          <th width="15%">View</th>  
                     </tr>  
           ';  
           while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
           {  
                $output .= '  
                     <tr>  
                          <td>' . $row["title"] . '</td>  
                          <td><input type="button" name="edit" value="Edit" id="'.$row["id"] .'" class="btn btn-info btn-xs edit_data" /></td>  
                          <td><input type="button" name="view" value="view" id="' . $row["id"] . '" class="btn btn-info btn-xs view_data" /></td>  
                     </tr>  
                ';  
           }  
           $output .= '</table>';  
      }  
      echo $output;  
 }  
 ?>
```

fetch.php

```
  <?php  
 //fetch.php  
 include_once 'core/init.php';
 if(isset($_POST["products_id"]))  
 {  
      $query = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE id = '".$_POST["products_id"]."'";  
      $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);  
      $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);  
      echo json_encode($row);  
 }  
 ?>
```

Comment: I'd like to attempt at helping but that wall of text hurts, please try to format / reduce the amount of text to form a concise question.

Comment: open to SQL injection exploits

Comment: Please target the issue and post the code in here. try to display php errors in this case. 
Posting your whole script is so useless since there's includes and database connections.

Comment: please narrow down your problem to a [minimal, complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Kisaragi ok, I have reformatted my question. Would love some help with this issue. It is the very last piece of the puzzle and the site will be complete.

Comment: If I knew the answer to that specific question I would have never posted this post on here @adamlab

Comment: is that narrow enough? @Jeff

Comment: I understand that but that is not why I am on here. I can easily make prepared statements that will block that, I have just been stuck on this problem and it is my main focus at this time. But thank you for reminding me:) @nogad

Comment: Im kinda guessing here, but it looks like you are not featching the data again after you have added the new data..

Comment: @Örvar I originally found this post and changed the code to fit my database and site. There code works and mine doesn't. Maybe that will help someone help me figure out the issue I am not seeing.  http://www.webslesson.info/2016/10/php-ajax-update-mysql-data-through-bootstrap-modal.html

Comment: Have you tried to open the browsers developertool to see if there are any errors in the console?

Comment: @Örvar, yes that is the 1st thing I do before I reach out to forums for help.

Comment: How are you running the site? On XAMPP perhaps?

Comment: @Örvar, it is running off goDaddy hosting

Comment: I would recommend to debug in your browsers developer tool, from line  125 the jQuery code thats executes when the form is submitted.

Comment: It could be that the ajax call is not returning anything after the form has been submitted, so there could be a php server side error that you are not seeing. Im not that experienced with php, so im kinda guessing here that it could be that serverside errors dont surface up to the page.. Errors are logged, but you will have to check where they are on your goDaddy hosting. Regarding the developer tool, make sure you are cheking the console. Have a look at XAMPP, its a open source web server solution package perfect for local developement insted of using your hosting when developing and testing.

Comment: @Örvar, I am aware of the MAMP server, I used it before and works very well for debugging. I have checked the ErrorLog in the Files of GoDaddy and there is none. But since the code works on the site I got the source code from there has to be a issue with what I did when renaming things in the code. When I first got the code uploaded, I only changed the connection and it worked but now all of a sudden I changed a few more things and now It doesn't but the problem is I don't remember how the code originally was uploaded because I took it into sublime text and edited before uploading.

Comment: @Örvar, figured it out LOL. I was using the word "condition" in the database and it was a word that was already taken by the database and couldn't be used. Once I changed it to item_condition everything worked! Thank you though for trying to trouble shoot with me. Very respectful.

Comment: Awsome to hear you worked it out :)